# Where is configurable product variation suffix created?

Tags: magento2.4.1

Configurable product creates variation name suffix (color-size). Where can i remove this autogeneration?

Answer (score 0):

It's here:

`vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/Model/ProductVariationsBuilder.php:58`

```
<?php
...
    public function create(\Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface $product, $attributes)
    {
        $variations = $this->variationMatrix->getVariations($attributes);
        $products = [];
        foreach ($variations as $variation) {
            $price = $product->getPrice();
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $item */
            $item = $this->productFactory->create();
            $item->setData($product->getData());

            $suffix = '';
            foreach ($variation as $attributeId => $valueInfo) {
                $suffix .= '-' . $valueInfo['value'];
                $customAttribute = $this->customAttributeFactory->create()
                    ->setAttributeCode($attributes[$attributeId]['attribute_code'])
                    ->setValue($valueInfo['value']);
                $customAttributes = array_merge(
                    $item->getCustomAttributes(),
                    [
                        $attributes[$attributeId]['attribute_code'] => $customAttribute
                    ]
                );
                $item->setData('custom_attributes', $customAttributes);
            }
            $item->setPrice($price);
            $item->setName($product->getName() . $suffix);
            $item->setSku($product->getSku() . $suffix);
            $item->setVisibility(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Visibility::VISIBILITY_NOT_VISIBLE);
            $products[] = $item;
        }
        return $products;
    }
}
```

Around plugin should be your pick of choice to disable this feature, since the method is public.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to comment out . $suffix from line where item name is set (setName). Because i need this feature in SKU generation. It was only for testing but it did not work. Variation name is still with suffix on form field after steps "Generate Products". Is it even acceptable to straight comment it out and copy file to app folder?

Comment: @kristjanzzz let me check it for you ;)